# Disable fancybox on smaller resolutions

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm using this plugin, with success:

http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/

I was just wondering if there was any way at all I could disable the JS, if the user is on a screen smaller than 767px -- that is, just link to the image itself and not raise the lightbox? I've had a look through all of the similar questions, but none of their solutions have really worked, nor do I know how to implement them.

I can download and use Modernizr if it would help...?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which browsers you have to support but you could use 'window.matchMedia'. You can find the supported browsers here: http://caniuse.com/matchmedia.

As to to how you'd use it in your case:

```
if (window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 767px)" ).matches) {
    // Initialize fancyBox.
}
```

I didn't see anywhere that you'd have to handle changes to the screen size but if you do you can add a listener like so:

```
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 767px)" );
mediaQuery.addListener(handleWidthChanges);
handleWidthChanges(mediaQuery);

function handleWidthChanges(mediaQuery) {
    if (mediaQuery.match) {
        // Do nothing if fancyBox already initialized otherwise disable.
    } else {
        // Disable fancyBox if it's initialized otherwise do nothing.
    }
}
```

If you have to support browsers other than those that currently support 'window.matchMedia', Modernizr has this: http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq, that you can fall back on.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just found a css-only solution:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 540px){
    .fancybox {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```